# ToolStrip.Background only changes button's background (C#/.NET/WinForms)

Tags: c#, winforms, toolstrip

I want my ToolStrip Background to change when an Item is not saved.

To render the background of my toolstrip I use my own renderer:

```
    class ToolStripRenderer : ToolStripProfessionalRenderer
    {
        private MenuBarForm parent;

        public ToolStripRenderer(MenuBarForm Parent)
        {
            parent = Parent;
        }

        protected override void OnRenderToolStripBackground(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (parent.controlItems.Last().Unsaved)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(e.ToolStrip.ClientRectangle, SystemColors.ControlLightLight, Color.Red, 90, true), e.AffectedBounds);
            else
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(e.ToolStrip.ClientRectangle, SystemColors.ControlLightLight, SystemColors.ControlDark, 90, true), e.AffectedBounds);
        }
    }
```

The first time the toolstrip renders it renders correctly with a grey to dark grey design:

[image: CorrectToolstrip]

But when the bar should become red, only the buttons which the mouse hovers over become red:

[image: IncorrectToolstrip]

I would like the whole toolstrip the be red-colored at once.

I already tried changing `e.AffectedBounds` to `e.ToolStrip.Bounds`, to no avail.

Comment: Sounds like it dont think it need to update the control. Have you tried calling Invalidate() on the toolstrip? To force it to update?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have added it to the question.

Comment: Please don't post answer as a part of the question. it's confusing for future readers. Post it as an answer.

Comment: Instead of changing background color by drawing, you can create a new color table and override relevant properties to change background color, then use it when `UnSaved` changes.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I am not familiar with color tables. Could you sample code in which a toolstrip backgroundcolor is changed based on a property using your color table.

Comment: Yes, I'll post an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I Found this solution Thanks to FSDaniel comment:**

By adding `Invalidate()` to the end of the `OnRenderToolStripBackground` the toolstrip did indeed become fully red but also caused the application to go into a infinite loop. I solved this by creating an event that was triggered by changing the `UnSaved` property. The form that has the toolstrip then subscribed a method to this event which called `toolstrip.Invalidate()`. This way `Invalidate()` is only used when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom color table inheriting [`ProfessionalColorTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.professionalcolortable(v=vs.110).aspx) and override relevant properties to change background color:

```
public class CustomColorTable : ProfessionalColorTable
{
    public override Color ToolStripGradientBegin
    {
        get { return Color.Red; }
    }
    public override Color ToolStripGradientMiddle
    {
        get { return Color.Red; }
    }
    public override Color ToolStripGradientEnd
    {
        get { return SystemColors.ControlLightLight; }
    }
}
```

To change your `ToolStrip` background, assign a new [`ToolStripProfessionalRenderer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripprofessionalrenderer(v=vs.110).aspx) which uses your custom color table to [`ToolStripManager.Renderer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.renderer(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
ToolStripManager.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new CustomColorTable());
```

To set the original professional renderer:

```
ToolStripManager.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. This solution doesn't work for me unfortunately. I tried adding your CustomColorTable with this code to change the renderer `
            if (controlItems.Last().Unsaved)
                ToolStripManager.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer();
            else
                ToolStripManager.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new CustomColorTable());`

Comment: To test the solution it's enough to set `RenderMode` property of your `ToolStrip` to `ManagerRenderMode` then change `ToolStripManager.Renderer` when you need. To arrange an independent test from your `UnSaved` property you can call `ToolStripManager.Renderer = new ToolStripProfessionalRenderer(new CustomColorTable());` in a button click to make sure it works.

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem applying the answer. It's tested and works properly.

Comment: In my previous solution I did not use a `ToolStripManager`. does the `ToolStripManager` need to be connected to the `ToolStrip` for this to work? My `ToolStrip` is also inside a `ToolStripContainer` maybe this interferes with the `ToolStripManager`?

Comment: Your `ToolStrip` will use a manager if you set `RenderMode` property of your `ToolStrip` to `ManagerRenderMode`. It's the main mechanism for skinning `ToolStrip`.